# users.getFullUser из Telegram APi не работает с некоторых аккаунтов

Tags: telegram, mtproto

Почему функция users.getFullUser не работает при авторизации с вновь созданного аккаунта?

Пытаюсь сделать приложение для работы с Telegram. Использую библиотеку mtproto-core (хотя это скорее всего не важно). Регистрирую приложение, используя свой личный аккаунт Telergram (получаю api_id и api_hash). С помощью функции users.getFullUser получаю информацию о любых юзерах по их id.
Теперь беру новую симку с новым номером, создаю новый Telegram-аккаунт на этот номер, регистрирую, используя его, новое приложение с новыми api_id и api_hash и запускаю свое приложение с новыми api_id, api_hash, phone_number и code. Теперь функция users.getFullUser отдает информацию только для для моего собственного user_id. Для всех остальных генерируется ошибка 400 USER_ID_INVALID.
Почему такое может быть и как это побороть?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Отредактировал исходное сообщение.

Comment: Нашли решение этой проблемы?

Comment: Нет. Не понимаю. С некоторых аккаунтов все работает, а с остальных - нет. Не только users.getFullUser. С неработающих аккаунтов и messages.sendMessage также отдает 400 PEER_ID_INVALID, если писать кому нибудь кроме самаго себя. Если пишешь на свой user_id - сообщение отправляется.